# phantomjs doesn't support flash player in windows machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am developing a python script to take screenshots from many websites. for this I am using below tools,

> phantomjs with selenium
>   python
>   windows PC

I have used pyside(instead of phantomjs) for that job but I faced many issues on pyside..

now I have found phantomjs tool from Google.com, I have used phantomjs with selenium for python in windows machine it is working flawless. but it has only one issue phantomjs doesn't support flash player, so am not able to process youtube and some flash websites.. please give me the some quick fix for this

Comment: If it doesn't support it, how do you want to "fix" a missing feature?

Answer (score 3):

PhantomJS does not and probably will not support Flash and other plugins (see [here](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html)).

But you can use [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/features.html) in your Selenium tests, which is  a headless browser based on the Gecko engine. It does support the WebDriver protocol, so use it.

There is also a [fork of PhantomJS with Flash support](https://github.com/r3b/phantomjs), but it didn't merge changes in PhantomJS back into it, so it is standing still at version 1.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

Phantomjs now don't rely on xwindow enviroment since 1.5, also it has remove plugin support at that time. So there is no officially support for running flash player in current phantomjs version.

Howerver, there are so many project fork from the old phantomjs that has flash player enabled and keep update. You can try [r3b phantomjs](http://www.ryanbridges.org/2013/05/21/putting-the-flash-back-in-phantomjs/). Recently I had build a perfect service upon this project under ubuntu os.