# Using chrome headlessly with phantomjs or anything else

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to get video url from webpage, that video appears in flash while opening with firefox, so using chrome + selenium I am able to fetch video url.

Now I want to deploy my code on azure server, where chrome windows does not appears. So I tried with http://phantomjs.org/ . But phantomjs is not able to scrap what I could do with chrome+selenium.

```
#driver = webdriver.Chrome() This works well
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs') #this could not scrap 
def getVideoTrend(self, item):
    driver.get('https://in.news.yahoo.com/video/-184010283.html')
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('yvp-main'))
    self.yahoo_video_trend = []
    for s in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('yvp-main'):
        print "Processing link  - ", item['link']
        trend = item
        print item['description']
        trend['video_link'] = s.find_element_by_tag_name('video').get_attribute('src')
        print 
        print s.find_element_by_tag_name('video').get_attribute('src')
        self.yahoo_video_trend.append(trend)
```

Comment: Hi. Websites use request headers like `User-Agent` to determine the browser. try set phantomjs's user-agent and try again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [phantomjs doesn't support flash player in windows machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533595/phantomjs-doesnt-support-flash-player-in-windows-machine)